# How do I get the data to be sent to me in an email instead of populating on the same page?

Tags: php, forms

I am new to php and I have post forms down but not I want some of my imput fields to be required.

I want this form to force the user to fill out the required fields but then be directed to my process.php page which will send me an email with the data the form collected. Right now the data is being posted at the bottom of the page. Please help me direct the data to an email.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body> 

    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {

       if (empty($_POST["name"]))
         {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
       else
         {$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);}

       if (empty($_POST["email"]))
         {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
       else
         {$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);}

       if (empty($_POST["website"]))
         {$website = "";}
       else
         {$website = test_input($_POST["website"]);}

       if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
         {$comment = "";}
       else
         {$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);}

       if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
         {$genderErr = "Gender is required";}
       else
         {$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);}

    }

    function test_input($data)
    {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
    }
    ?>

    <h2>PHP Form</h2>
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
       Name: <input type="text" name="name">
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       Website: <input type="text" name="website">
       <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
       <br><br>
       Gender:
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>

    <?php
    echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $email;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $website;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $comment;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $gender;
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I have the code to collect that data and email it. i just don't know how to get the form to validate and then direct to the process.php page.

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    $to      = 'str@xxxxxxxx.com';
    $subject = 'Executive Plaza Contact Form Response';
    $message.= "Name: $name \n";
    $message.= "Email: $email \n";
    $message.= "email: $email \n";
    $message.= "comment: $comment \n";
    $message.= "gender: $gender \n";
    $headers = "From: Eleven55\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);




    header('Location: thank-you.php');
```

Comment: Post the form to itself (e.g. the same URL as the page displaying it) then check to see if you've got `empty($_POST)` ... if you have, assume first load and display the form. If not validate the form ... if it fails validation just redisplay the form the the `values` loaded from the `$_POST` - if the form PASSES validation, then use PHP's `mail()` function to email you the relevant stuff you want; **finally** hand off to a "thank you" page with a header redirect - that way the POST isn't cached on that new page.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$to='youremail@yourdomain.com';
$subject='Form data';
$body = "Name :$name \n ...";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

Read the mail function documentation for more info

My bad. Do this
    `document.forms.onsubmit = function(){ //onsubmit event

    //validate form data using getElementById().val and so on

    if(formdataisnotvalid){

      alert('descriptive error message');

      return false; // this will prevent the form from submitting

    }`

Comment: I have this on my process.php page.. I am just unsure on how to get the form to validate and then direct it to that page.

Comment: My bad. Do this  
    document.forms.onsubmit = function(){ //onsubmit event
    //validate form data using getElementById().val and so on
    if(formdataisnotvalid){
      alert('descriptive error message');
      return false; // this will prevent the form from submitting
    }
}

Comment: I am confused. Sorry. Where would I put that?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the PHP mail() function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).  It is basic and should get you started.

```
$to='you@domain.com';
$subject='Form data';
$body = "{$name} says {$comment}.  \n Contact {$name} at {$email} or {$website}.  \n {$name} is a {$gender}";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```